# Getting the indices of misclassified rows of data using scikit

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

When I use the code

```
import numpy as np

y_test = np.asarray(y_test)
misclassified = np.where(y_test != clf.predict(X_test))
```

for binary as well as 3 way classification, we get a tuple of 2 which a long list of indices (I presume) for X_test. These indices/numbers in each of the 2 tuples have repetitions as well. Can someone explain what does the misclassified supposed to look like.

When i print it using the code

```
clf=RandomForestClassifier(min_samples_leaf=20);
    model=clf.fit(X_train,y_train);
    #rf=RandomForestRegressor();
    accu=clf.score(x_test,y_test);
    pred=clf.predict(x_test);
    cnf_matrix=confusion_matrix(y_test,pred);
    print("Accuracy:",accu," Confusion matrix:",cnf_matrix);

    ##Test for false negatives
    np_y_test=np.asarray(y_test);
    print("test ",np_y_test.shape, " ", x_test.shape, " ",pred.shape);
    miss_arr= np.where(np_y_test!=pred);


    print(type(miss_arr)," mispredict ", miss_arr);
```

, mine looks like this:

```
Accuracy: 0.7131782945736435  Confusion matrix: [[32  0 15]
 [ 5  0 17]
 [ 0  0 60]]
test shape of np.array(y_test) (129, 1)  shape of x_test (129, 16) shape of clf.predict(x_test)  (129,)
<class 'tuple'>  mispredict  (array([  0,   0,   0, ..., 128, 128, 128]), array([19, 20, 34, ..., 49, 50, 51]))
```

As you can this is for 3 way classification. I get similar outputs for 2 way classification as well.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a broadcasting error because the dimension of `y_test` is `(129, 1)`, making it artificially seem like a 2-D array. As a result, the entries in `clf.predict(...)` get repeated for each entry in `y_test`, and you end up with too many output indices from the `where` operation.

I made a toy example with random data to demonstrate:

```
In [12]: x
Out[12]: 
array([[ 0.37842257],
       [ 0.8635568 ],
       [ 0.03439733],
       [ 0.57522837],
       [ 0.79302198],
       [ 0.37139872],
       [ 0.55252899],
       [ 0.76331397],
       [ 0.27676114],
       [ 0.20412743]])

In [13]: y
Out[13]: 
array([ 0.18595721,  0.61417275,  0.6511883 ,  0.57157444,  0.84596623,
        0.15789458,  0.62759   ,  0.91146098,  0.02160262,  0.34704034])

In [14]: x.shape
Out[14]: (10, 1)

In [15]: y.shape
Out[15]: (10,)

In [16]: np.where(x != y)
Out[16]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
        4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
        6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9,
        9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2,
        3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
        6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
        9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1,
        2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))

In [17]: len(np.where(x != y)[0])
Out[17]: 100
```

But now note what happens if I first reshape `x` to make it have the same 1-D dimension format as `y`:

```
In [18]: np.where(x.reshape(10) != y)
Out[18]: (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),)
```

This is correct: it's just the 1-D set of indices where the two separate 1-D arrays are mismatching.

For your case, it suggests you can fix the problem with just

```
y_test.reshape(len(y_test))
```

when passing it into `np.where`.

Comment: Thanks. Thats very helpful. One more item.. so in case of 3 way classification of say, true label = 0,1,2, I should be able to get list of rows where y==2 and is misclassifed by np.where(x.reshape(10)!=y and y==2) ?

Comment: You could use multiplication to express that: `np.where((x.reshape(10) != y) * (y == 2))`. This works because `y == 2` returns a boolean array, and when cast into an arithmetical operation like multiplication, it makes `True` act like 1 and `False` act like 0. So the elements would have to evaluate to `True` in both of the boolean conditions inside of `where` to end up providing an index in the result.

Comment: If you don't want to use multiplication for it since it can be deceiving when reading the code, you can also use [`np.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html), such as `np.where(np.logical_and(x.reshape(len(x)) != y, y == 2))`. The syntax is slightly longer, but it's much clearer what operation is being applied.

Comment: using the logical and or * (y==2) again gives an output which is hard to understand. I get a tuple of length 2 and printing the first tuple gives me a list of 0.

Comment: @FahadSayeed The output of `where` for this operation should be a tuple of length 1, so something is still not correct regarding the dimensions of `np_y_test` and `pred`. You should update your question showing this new code you are using and print out the new output giving you problems.

Answer (score -1):

using the logical and or * (y==2) again gives an output which is hard to understand. I get a tuple of length 2 and printing the first tuple gives me a list of many 0s though the length of the first tuple matches the number of mismatches from the confusion matrix.